# Importing dependencies using a class that inherits from Lazy<>

Tags: mef, lazy-evaluation, import

Can you import using a class that inherits from Lazy rather than Lazy itself?  I am exporting using a derivitive of `ExportAttribute` that contains metadata.

```
[FeatureExport(/* Feature Metadata Parameters */)]
public class Feature : IFeature
{
    // Feature Properties
}

public class FeatureReference : Lazy<IFeature, IFeatureMetadata>
{

}

public class Consumer
{
    [ImportMany]
    public IEnumerable<FeatureReference> FeatureReferences { get; set; }
}
```

Is this possible?  Would it work?  I could try it myself, but I'm in development so I don't actually have any code written.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it won't work I'm afraid. You would need to implement your own programming model extension (either a custom part/catalog or possibly via `ReflectionModelServices`) to make this work.

MEF would have to create the `FeatureReference` object in order to set it, and considering that `FeatureReference` might have any constructor imaginable, you can guess why this isn't supported.

Comment: Thanks.  Now if only I knew how to instantiate a templated type without calling it by a new name in my UML tool (Modelio) but that's a completely different problem. :)